# Is there a way to make the Gtranslate plugin work with WordPress RTL/LTR themes for multi-language site direction?

Tags: wordpress, function, plugins

i am using **gtranslate** plugin in my **wordpress** website
my theme support RTL/LTR but when i translate website the direction not changed
can i find function of any way to merge/Compian between gtranslate and **rtl test plugin**
to change website direction to **LTR for English** and **RTL for Arabic/Hebrew**
thank you lot

find solution to merge/Compian between Gtranslate plugin and RTL test plugin in wordpress